# Locally free $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ modules are not projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, fake-proofs, ringed-spaces

Let $(X , \mathcal{O}_{X})$ be a locally ringed space. I know that in general it is not true that locally free $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ modules are projective in the category of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ modules ([this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200251/is-a-locally-free-sheaf-projective-in-the-category-of-mathcalo-x-modules-wh) post on mathoverflow gives a counterexample on an integral affine scheme). As it is so, I don't understand where is the flaw in the following proof.

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a finitely presented $\mathcal{O}_{X}$, i.e. locally it there exists an exact sequence
$$
\mathcal{O}_{X}^{n} \rvert_{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}^{m} \rvert_{U} \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rvert_{U} \rightarrow 0
$$
where $U \subset X$ is an open subset, then for every $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ module $\mathcal{G}$ we have a natural isomorphism
$$
\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G} \right) _{x} \simeq \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \left( \mathcal{F}_{x} , \mathcal{G}_{x} \right)
$$
where $x \in X$ and the subscript means the stalk of the sheaf.
Therefore, if we have an exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathcal{G}' \rightarrow \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}'' \rightarrow 0
$$
applying $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, - \right)$ we get the exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}' \right) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G} \right) \rightarrow \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}'' \right).
$$ 
Now, if $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free on rank $n$, looking at the stalk at a point $x \in X$ and using what said before this exact sequence corresponds to the sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathcal{G}'^{\oplus n}_{x} \rightarrow  \mathcal{G}^{\oplus n}_{x} \rightarrow  \mathcal{G}''^{\oplus n}_{x}
$$
which is also exact on the right. Hence, the sequence with the $\mathcal{H}om$ is exact, and $\mathcal{F}$ is projective.

Where am I losing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What your argument proves is that the *sheaf* Hom-functor $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, - \right)$ is exact.  That's not what it means for $\mathcal{F}$ to be projective, though.  For $\mathcal{F}$ to be projective, the ordinary Hom-functor $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, - \right)$ (with values in abelian groups, not sheaves) must be exact.  This functor is obtained by taking the global sections of the sheaf Hom-functor.  Since taking global sections is not exact in general, $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, - \right)$ may fail to be exact even though $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_{X}} \left( \mathcal{F}, - \right)$ is exact.

Comment: I see. Thank you, I had in mind the wrong definition.